# What is a good benchmark for A* (AStar)?

Tags: performance, algorithm, benchmarking, path-finding, a-star

I wrote myself an A*, it works quite well and now comes the time to evaluate its performance (potentially against other solutions to see how it performs).

For both having visual feedback and fun I use it as an image *maze solver*. First - I know this is not what A* has been primarily designed for, but I think it is quite a good way (yet not the only one) to test it. Agree ? I've kept it very simple : white pixels are nodes and other colours are walls.

I've thought of throwing [this maze](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/MAZE.png) (large picture) at it, but I know that it will

- obviously take some time, because it has more than 3 000 000 edges (and a bit less than half as walls, but still)
- not necessarily be a good indicator, over-sized environment

To sum up : what kind of environment is a good stress-test for A* ? What's the order of magnitude of graphs in applicative A* (in games for example) ?

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense - I don't think a "generally good indicator" *exists at all*. Different tweaks work better or worse, depending on the problem; some, like using a boolean grid to store the closed-"list", do not even apply *at all* in many situations but *can be* (but aren't necessarily) awesome when they do.

Comment: @harold There may not be "one bench to rule them all", that's for sure, but I think there are interesting things to try. I'm not talking optimization, I was wondering if the kind of maze as the one I linked isn't a very specific case that isn't representative of the global use for the algorithm.

Comment: Well, it's an interesting test at least, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 5):

A good stress test is a digital road network for
1) part of a big country (like spain, france, germany) , then
2) The whole country. (some million nodes)

OpenStreetMap provides such data, but it is much work to import that to a graph.

Comment: That's a very good idea, but I am afraid it is beyond my expertise (I assume that's very complex data). I'll have a look anyway !

Comment: @tehinternetsismadeofcatz GraphHopper already imports large data from openstreetmap easily (e.g. world wide), so that is no longer much work. It implements an A* but you can easily implement your own (in Java) and more important: you could compare and improve performance :)

Comment: @AlexWien for me/graphhopper the world wide scenario has approx. 80mio nodes and ~110mio edges for car. germany has 9mio edges and 7mio nodes

Comment: @Thanks for the info. Navis usually calculate shorest route with a hierarchical network: but on server side, you have memory for 80 mio nodes.

Comment: @Karussell unfortunately I use C++, but that's interesting.

Comment: @AlexWien on Android I can use a memory mapped approach where several million nodes works also + correctly (only for the hierarchical network) or via heuristics

Comment: @Karussell does this memory mapped approach currently work, or is this as idea for future work? (the top hierarchy: higways, high level roads, should easily fit in mem for european continent)

Comment: @AlexWien already works (see MMapDataAccess)! For the hierarchy: I'm using a bit different hierarchy (contraction hierarchies) where every node is on a separate level :), hmmh, but yes, you are right I could just keep the first 1k nodes in memory, this could improve especially the very first queries! But if you like you can try and implement some other hierarchical algorithm :) !

Comment: @Karussell: In Navit OpenSource this works as follows: load detail map for current Position (20x20 km may increase till high level road found) load detail for destination,  load  high prio streets streets for bounding box of current to destination. Then route.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a serial version of [Parallel New Bidirectional A*](http://www.dimap.ufrn.br/csbc2011/anais/eventos/contents/ENIA/ENIA_Sessao_6_Artigo_1_Rios.pdf) on a terrain map of about 420 x 760 hexagons (over 325,000 hexagons total). The most difficult long diagonal path on this map, of about 1080 steps, completes in about 0.45 seconds elapsed time on a single i7 core, with just under 90,000 closed-set elements upon completion.

Note that terrain maps have *maze-like* qualities as far as Dijkstra and A* are concerned, because the wide range in step costs (fr0m 2 to 10+ for this map) ensure that all admissible heuristics are inefficient.